# JSON adding one extra row in jquery with blank data

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am adding my data in a `JSON` for input elements but what happens is IF I add two rows, in json three rows gets added. I dont know why.

Below is my json

```
[{"VendorCode":"Vendor 1","FromDate":"1/1/1970","ToDate":"1/1/1970"},{"VendorCode":"Vendor 1","FromDate":"2/1/1970","ToDate":"1/1/1970"},{"VendorCode":"","FromDate":"","ToDate":""}]
```

Its showing three rows, but actually It has 2 rows. Here is the code for saving.

```
 $(".vendorDaterow").each(function () {

        var ID = "";
        var Name = "";
        var ToDate = "";
        var FromDate = "";
        var NameValues = [];

        var allInputs = $(this).find("input");
        var objectToAdd = {};
        var Code = "";

            for (var i = 0; i < allInputs.length; i++) {
                if (allInputs[i].name == "nmVendorData") {
                    objectToAdd["VendorName"] = allInputs[i].value;
                    Name = allInputs[i].value;
                    NameValues = Name.split('/');
                    Code = NameValues[0];
                    Name = NameValues[0];

                }
                else if (allInputs[i].name == "spFromDate") {
                    objectToAdd["ToDate"] = allInputs[i].value;
                    FromDate = allInputs[i].value;
                }
                else if (allInputs[i].name == "spToDate") {
                    objectToAdd["FromDate"] = allInputs[i].value;
                    ToDate = allInputs[i].value;
                }
            }

        arrVendorValues.push({
            "VendorCode": Code,
            "FromDate": FromDate,
            "ToDate": ToDate
        });
    });
```

**UPDATED**

```
<tr id="vendorlisttr1">
                            <td>
                                <div class="row noPadding vendorForm">
                                    <div class="vendorDaterow">
                                        <div class="vendorName" id="dvVendorNameData1">
                                            <label>SP Vender Name</label><span><input type="text" value="" name="nmVendorData" id="txtVendorName1" /></span>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="vendorFromDate">
                                            <label>From Date</label><span class="datepicker"><input type="text" value="" name="spFromDate" id="spFromDate1" /><i class="fa fa-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="vendorToDate">
                                            <label>To Date</label><span class="datepicker"><input type="text" value="" name="spToDate" id="spToDate1" /><i class="fa fa-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="add">
                                        <i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                    </div>

                                </div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
```

Comment: Since you're getting 3 objects pushed into `arrVendorValues` it would be logical to assume that `$(".vendorDaterow")` refers to 3 elements.  Since you don't show the HTML this is attached to (you should, this question is not an [mcve]) it's impossible for the reader to validate this assumption.

Comment: @Tibrogargan: added the html in question. On add class click the row is generated dynamically

Comment: You're not showing the HTML.  You're showing some random snippet that you think contains the problem.  The problem is probably in whatever code is handling the `'click'` event, not in what you included.

Comment: Please add the code under the add button

Comment: You could replace your code with something like: `$(".vendorDaterow").each(function () { arrVendorValues.push( { "VendorCode": $(this).find('input[name="nmVendorData"]').val().split('/')[0], "FromDate": $(this).find('input[name="spFromDate"]').val(), "ToDate": $(this).find('input[name="spToDate"]').val() }) })`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be use **`class`** as **`"vendorDaterow"`** three times. But two have inputs or **`check the not empty`** conditions. So check the following in your code.

```
arrVendorValues.push({
    "VendorCode": Code,
    "FromDate": FromDate,
    "ToDate": ToDate
});

Into

if(Code != ""){
    arrVendorValues.push({
        "VendorCode": Code,
        "FromDate": FromDate,
        "ToDate": ToDate
    });
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: @VVVV Okay fine, or check the not empty conditions :-)

Answer (score 0):

I think extra added row `{"VendorCode":"","FromDate":"","ToDate":""}` does not have any values. So you can try this,

```
if(Code && FromDate && ToDate) { // This you can change accordingly
  arrVendorValues.push({
        "VendorCode": Code,
        "FromDate": FromDate,
        "ToDate": ToDate
    });
}
```

Can you update question with appropriate HTML content ? It may help to understand the extra iteration.